# model softmax or thresholded values for evaluation

Tags: neural-networks

When calculating evaluation metrics for semantic segmentation, such as mean IoU, Dice, Hausdorff Distance, and Precision, should we be passing in the model softmax results? Or should we be passing in the softmax-thresholded values (So that it's all 0/1) before calculating the metrics? Mathematically, both should work but is there one that's used more often/more correct?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!